# Java-Creating Entity Class from dataBase tables programmatically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to create an entity class from the database table.

Now I am working with pure Java configuration with Spring + Hibernate and my question is: how to create the model class(entity) using Openjpa -Reverse Mapping tool without using persistence.xml file?

Comment: you can use myeclipse for that.

Comment: But i want it by programmatically @Pratik

Comment: I think its not a small job to convert programmatically.

Comment: then How ReverseMappingTool is possible.But its not working for myself

Comment: This may help you. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/jpatutorial-2-092215.html

Comment: Thank u @Pratik .its possible to create manually using eclipse..But i need at run time..anyway thank you

Comment: @Arunkumar.P-SoftwareDeveloper you need to create the entity class at runtime ? this sounds very messy, and may not even be possible. Why ? The database schema is changing at runtime - this is very bad.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create manually using eclipse.

you can try below link for reference purpose.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/jpatutorial-2-092215.html

Answer (score 0):

In intellij, right click in persistence tool window 
`generate persistence mapping > by database schema`, will give you options just accept the defaults, woks for me.

(intellij > netbeans > eclipse == true)

Answer (score 0):

G9 plugin from Marketplace in Spring Tool Suit or Eclipse did job done.

1. Install Plugin G9
2. Select Project (JAVA)
3. Import "Import Database Model"
4. Select JDBC Driver (In my case mysql)
5. Maintain JDBC Connection

   - New
   - Provide *Driver Name, Add Jar, Port, Driver Class and connection url along with schema (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{schema_name})*
6. Close JDBC Connection Box
7. Port, DB Name, User Name and PWD
8. Fetch

Reference URL https://www.esito.no/produkter/dbimport/